# WPF Datagrid programmatically set a multi-selection as one step

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, multi-select

Is there any way to set a multi-selection programmatically on (virtualized) DataGrid (even better to modify the current selection by Added/Removed items collections), not one by one but in one step - to trigger just one SelectionChanged event?
Or some way to defer the SelectedItems changes processing like the following pseudocode:

```
dataGrid.SelectionChangeStart(); // start to queue selection changes
ModifySelectedItems(dataGrid.SelectedItems); // add/remove items
dataGrid.SelectionChangeEnd(); // now process all the changes at once
```

EDIT: The Datagrid has Extended selection mode.

Comment: try to set `datagrid.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;`

Comment: I have set it to Extended, I can select more items by modifying the SelectedItems content (or changing the IsSelected flag) - but these methods processes the selection change one by one. I want to force DataGrid to process a collection of selection changes at once in one 'run'.